# Unable to read file properly issue with my constructor

Tags: java, file, class

I am attempting to read a CSV file and when I attempt to execute the code it returns all nulls. I am confused on how I can properly print this out without creating a new constructor.

I have tried redoing the read method in CustomerList multiple. It prints all the fields that I want but does not return the data I want.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package assignment08;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

/**
 *
 * @author banth
 */
public class Assignment08 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.io.FileNotFoundException
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        boolean b = false;
    // Read file
        System.out.println("Read file");
        CustomerList cl = CustomerList.read("Customers.csv");
        if(cl != null) {
            System.out.println("Read: " + cl.size() + " records");
            System.out.println(cl.toString() + "\n\n\n");
        } else {
            System.out.println("File read error.");
            return;
        }
    // Test get and set for CustomerList
        System.out.println("Test get and set for CustomerList");
        System.out.println("x = " + cl.get(0));
        Customer c = cl.get(0);
        c.setFirstName("Homer");
        cl.set(c, 0);
        System.out.println("x = " + cl.get(0));
        System.out.println("\n\n\n");

    // Test indexOf and update
        System.out.println("Test indexOf and update");
        System.out.println("idx = " + cl.indexOf(34));
        System.out.println("Customer with id 35 = \n" + cl.get(cl.indexOf(35)));
    // Update an existing Customer
        b = cl.update(35, 100.0);
        if(b) {
            System.out.println("Update successful");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Update not successful");
        }
        System.out.println("Customer with id 35 = \n" + cl.get(cl.indexOf(35)));
        cl.update(41, 150.0);
        cl.update(59, 200.0);
        cl.update(72, 250.0);
    // Update a non-existing Customer
        b = cl.update(350, 100.0);
        if(b) {
            System.out.println("Update successful");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Update not successful");
        }
        System.out.println("\n\n\n");
    // Test remove
        System.out.println("Test remove");
        System.out.println("x = " + cl.get(1));
    // Remove an existing Customer
        c = cl.remove(1);
        if(c != null) {
            System.out.println("Deleted\n" + c.toString());
        } else {
            System.out.println("No Customer deleted");
        }   
    // Remove an existing Customer
        c = cl.remove(101);
        if(c != null) {
            System.out.println("Deleted\n" + c.toString());
        } else {
            System.out.println("No Customer deleted");
        }
        System.out.println("\n\n\n");
    // Write file
        b = CustomerList.write(cl, "NewCustomers.csv");
        if(b) {
            System.out.println("File write successful");
        } else {
        System.out.println("File write failed");
        }
    }



}
```

//Person.java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package assignment08;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author banth
 */
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zipCode;    

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String address, String city, String state, String zipCode) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.address = address;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.zipCode = zipCode;    
    }

    protected Person() {

    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return this.city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }

    public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FirstName: " + firstName + "\nLastName: " + lastName + "\nAddress: " + address + "\nCity: " + city + "\nState: " + state + "\nZipCode: " + zipCode;
    }

    public String toCSV() {
        return this.firstName + "," + this.lastName + "," + this.address + "," + this.city
                + "," + this.state + "," + this.zipCode;
    }

    public void copy(Person p) {       
        firstName = p.firstName;
        lastName = p.lastName;
        address = p.address;
        city = p.city;
        state = p.state;
        zipCode = p.zipCode;
    }

    public void copy(String firstName, String lastName, String address, String city, String state, String zipCode) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.address = address;
        this.city = city;
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    @Override
    public Person clone() {
        Person p = new Person(this.firstName, this.lastName, this.address, this.city, this.state, this.zipCode);
        return p;
    }
}
```

//Customer.java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package assignment08;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author banth
 */
public class Customer extends Person{
    private int customerID;
    private double grossSales;

    public Customer(int customerID, double grossSales, String firstName, String lastName, String address, String city, String state, String zipCode) {
        super(firstName, lastName, address, city, state, zipCode);
        this.customerID = customerID;
        this.grossSales = grossSales;
    }

    public Customer(String s, int customerID, double grossSales, String firstName, String lastName, String address, String city, String state, String zipCode) {
        super(firstName, lastName, address, city, state, zipCode);
        copyCSV(s);
    }

    protected Customer() {

    }

    public int getCustomerID() {
        return customerID;
    }

    public void setCustomerID(int customerID) {
        this.customerID = customerID;
    }

    public double getGrossSales() {
        return grossSales;
    }

    public void setGrossSales(double grossSales) {
        this.grossSales = grossSales;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CustomerID: " + customerID + "\nGrossSales: " + grossSales + super.toString();
    }

    public String toCSV() {
        return this.customerID + "," + this.grossSales + "," + super.toCSV();
    }

    public void copy(Customer c) {
        super.copy(c);
        customerID = c.customerID;
        grossSales = c.grossSales;
    }

    public void copy(int customerId, double grossSales, String firstName, String lastName, String address, String city, String state, String zipCode) {
        super.copy(firstName, lastName, address, city, state, zipCode);
        this.customerID = customerId;
        this.grossSales = grossSales;
    }

    public Customer clone() {
        Customer c = new Customer(this.customerID, this.grossSales, this.getFirstName(), this.getLastName(), this.getAddress(), this.getCity(), this.getState(), this.getZipCode());
        return c;    
    }

    public int compareTo(Customer c) {
        int returnValue = 0;

        if (this.customerID > c.customerID) {
            returnValue = -1;
        } else if (this.customerID < c.customerID) {
            returnValue = 1;
        } else {
            returnValue = 0;
        }

        return returnValue;
    }

    public void copyCSV(String s) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        String[] a = s.split(",");

        list = Arrays.asList(a);

        this.copy(Integer.parseInt(list.get(0)), Double.parseDouble(list.get(1)), list.get(2), 
                list.get(3), list.get(4), list.get(5), list.get(6), list.get(7));
    }

}
```

CUSTOMERLIST.java

```
///*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    package assignment08;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    /**
     *
     * @author banth
     */
    public class CustomerList {
        public Customer[] cl;
        public int size; 

        public CustomerList() {
            this.cl = new Customer[4];
        }

        public int size() {
            return this.size = cl.length;
        }

        public Customer get(Integer i) {
            if (i < 0 || i >= size) {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("null");
            }
            return cl[i];
        }


        public boolean set(Customer c,Integer i) {
            if (i < 0 || i >= size) {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("null");
            } else {
                cl[i] = c;
                return true;
            }
        } 

        public void add(Customer c) {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                if (cl[i] == null) {
                    cl[i] = c;
                } else {
                    if (i == size) {
                        Customer[] temp = new Customer[size * 2];
                        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                            temp[j] = cl[j];
                        }
                        cl[size] = c;
                        size++;

                        }
                    }   
                }
        }

        public Customer remove(Integer i) {
            if (i < 0 || i >= size) {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("null");
            }
                Customer temp = cl[i];
                for (int j = 0; j < cl.length - 1; j++) {
                    cl[i] = cl[i + 1];
            }
            return temp;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
          String s = " ";
            double sum = 0;
            for(Customer c: cl){
                if(c == null)
                    s = "";
                else
                    s += c + " \n";

            }


            for(Customer c: cl){
                if (c ==  null)
                    sum += 0;
                else
                    sum += c.getGrossSales();

            }

            return s + "\n" +  "Total Gross Sales = " + Double.toString(sum);
        }

        public static CustomerList read(String fn) throws FileNotFoundException {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(fn));
            CustomerList ab = new CustomerList();
            String s;
            input.nextLine();
                while(input.hasNextLine()) {
                    s = input.nextLine();
                    Customer c = new Customer(s);
                    System.out.println(c);
                    ab.add(c);
                }
                input.close();
                return ab;
        }


    //Write is facing the same problems as read. We can't access the toCSV() method from Customer.
    public static boolean write(CustomerList cl, String fn) throws FileNotFoundException {
        boolean a = false;
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new File(fn));
       // try {
            for (int i = 0; i < cl.size; i++) {
                Customer cd = new Customer();
                cd.toCSV();

         //   }
       // } catch (FileNotFoundException s) {
         //   System.out.println("File does not exist please try again: ");
           // return a;
        } return a = true;
    }

    //I utilized the sort function it said to and assume this will work as expected.
    public void sort() {
        Arrays.sort(cl);
    }


    public int indexOf(int id) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if(cl[i].getCustomerID() == id) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public boolean update(int id, double amt) {
        boolean test;
        int index = indexOf(id);
        if(index == -1) {
            System.out.println("CustomerID not present");
            test = false;
        } else {
            amt += cl[index].getGrossSales();
            test = true;
        }
        return test;
    }
}
```

My expected results are for the file to print the customerID: the gross sales, the first name, last name, address, city, state, and zip code of each person.

My issue I think is in my read in my customer list class; I am trying to create a new string to take in the data.

Comment: In your CustomerList add(..) method what is the value of `size` variable ? is it 0 ?

Comment: @sachin size is to the customer length which is set to 4

Comment: I see the add method is void and updates the `cl` which is a `Customer` array. The read method returns the `CustomerList` as such. Before the add method return statement can you check what is the length of `cl` variable or print the values ?

Comment: in the debugger console, it says the size is 8 @Sachin

Comment: Try stepping through your code using a debugger - and look at the values stored in your variables at each step. Once you spot something that is not what you expected, edit your question to ask about that specific problem. Otherwise, we're just debugging your application for you.

Comment: @Jason it's not getting any of the data. It can read the file perfectly fine but it crashes once it tries to get the first name

Comment: Please edit your question to show which line throws an exception / crashes and exactly what message you receive.

Comment: At the moment, I don't know how your code compiles. You have this line of code: `Customer c = new Customer(s);` but there is no matching constructor in `Customer`.